# How to use split() to convert 1.18.0-AAA-1 into 1.18.0 js

Tags: javascript

How to use the javascript `split` `splice` `slice` methods to convert the:

`1.18.0-AAA-1` into `1.18.0.`

Comment: It's pretty easy and basic thing to do in javascript..You should have done a google search first..You will get tons of tutorials..Here it is take a look at one to learn : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the initial value, determine that the portion you want is before the first hyphen, so use that as the delimiter for the split. Perform the split and then the first portion will be everything up to but not including that first hyphen. You don't need slice or splice for this - just split. Then just add the dot at the end for the trailing dot.

```
var x="1.18.0-AAA-1";
var y=x.split("-");//splits it at each "-";
var z=y[0]+".";//gives 1.18.0.
```

however if you are asking to use each of the threeemethods to yield the outcome, then this sounds like homework and you should try doing it on your own. Best way to learn is to try.

Answer (score 0):

Use split to create an array from your string

`var str = "1.18.0-AAA-1";
var parts = str.split("-"); // this returns the array ["1.18.0", "AAA", "1"]`

Now the easiest way to get what you want is doing:

`parts[0];`